# BootstrapToggle switch conditionally switch state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use [bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in one of my pages. The initial state is off / disabled.

The page loads several boolean values and stores them as hidden text. Then I have a script which looks them up via their IDs. Upon that hidden text it should toggle the slider.

I was able to get the hidden text and make the conditional check but I'm not able to toggle the slider for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var flags = [];
  var userID = '',
      toggleSlider = '';

  flags = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="activeFlag_"]');

  flags.forEach(function (flag) {
    userID = flag.id.split('_')[1];

    // This is where i search for the hidden text
    if (flag.firstChild.data == 'True') {
      // Nothing works here.
      $('#activeToggle_' + userID).bootstrapToggle('toggle');
    }
  });
});
```

And this is the html code that I need to work with:

```
    <p id="activeFlag_@user1">@item.activeFlag</p>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input id="activeToggle_user1" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would you try to add `console.log` inside `if(flag.firstChild.data == 'True')` block and see if it works?

Comment: BTW you already loaded `jQuery`, why you mixed plain JS with it? I think you should make your decision, stick with either jQuery or plain JS.

Comment: I'm able to get inside the if-block with no problems at all. I will add logging inside the if-block 2morrow since I'm at home now.
I'm still at the stage of learning by doing, so excuse my mixing of javascript and jquery.
Could you point out what lines are jquery, and which are javascript?

Comment: For example, JS: `document.querySelectorAll(` and `flag.firstChild`, jQuery: anywhere you used `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too opaque without any data example.
However one thing could be a cause of its problem:

```
if (flag.firstChild.data == 'True') {
```

Try to replace it with:

```
if (flag.firstElementChild.data == 'True') {
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp) you could find explanation:

> The firstChild property returns the first child node of the specified node, as a Node object.
>
> The difference between this property and firstElementChild, is that firstChild returns the first child node as an element node, a text node or a comment node (depending on which one's first), while firstElementChild returns the first child node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).
>
> **Note**: Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes (See "More Examples").

### Update after example code was added

For the example code you provided, you should change the split argument:

```
userID = flag.id.split('_')[1];
```

to:

```
userID = flag.id.split('_@')[1];
```

Thanks to **twain** for initial jsfiddle. I have updated it accordingly: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwegr4pn/1/)

Comment: flag.firstElementChild yielded null thus data is null also.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is, that the following part does not use the correct id for the toggle `$('#activeToggle_' + userID).bootstrapToggle('toggle');`

Your html ID is `activeToggle_user1`, but the js part above will probably resolve to `#activeToggle_1`. So the text `user` is missing here.

I created a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pbcrh5d2/

Comment: I copied your code and replaced mine, and still got the same result.
The funny thing is that I did:
`var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="#activeToggle_"]');`

Basically saying get me all elements whose id start with activeToggle_ and got a filled array.

Comment: I didn't adjust your js code, just your html part. The p-tag contains now `activeFlag_user1` instead of `activeFlag_1`. I guess your `@user1` just contains the id?

Comment: That is right, I thought that I made a typo somewhere but everything is correct.
I was debugging the section where I call bootstrapToggle('toggle')
` $('#activeToggle_' + userID).bootstrapToggle('toggle');`

Where userID
And watchted  $('#activeToggle_' + userID) and it gave me `i.fn.init(0)` with the length equal to 0.

Wierd!

Comment: When I enter into the console: `document.getElementById('activeToggle_user1')`

I get null...

Comment: what contains your `userID` in the `forEach`? Just the ID (e.g. 1) or the whole string (e.g user1). If its just the ID, you simply have to change `$('#activeToggle_' + userID).bootstrapToggle('toggle');` to `$('#activeToggle_user' + userID).bootstrapToggle('toggle');`

Comment: it conains a whole string like user1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason asp.net and javascript have a problem with coping together. I used asp.net to provide javascript to build the strings.
So I switched to the raw id that is used in the table.